# In need of function(using 'def') that devides two columns in a dataframe by row, and adds a new column that displays the result

Tags: python, pandas, function

After reading the dataframe, added a new column with a constant value by which i need to divide the already presented 'Population' value

```
#set directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/218214559/Desktop/Geo_Scripting/NewNamibia_data/Namibia")

#Reading data
data = pd.read_csv("Regional_Population.csv")
#Add column
data["New_val"] = ''
new = data.assign(New_val =10)
print(new)
```

output

```
          REGION_NAM  Population  New_val
    0        Zambezi       90596       10
    1         Erongo      150809       10
    2         Hardap       79507       10
    3          Karas       77421       10
    4   Kavango West      223352       10
    5   Kavango East      223352       10
    6         Kunene       86856       10
    7      Ohangwena      245446       10
    8        Omaheke       71233       10
    9        Omusati      243166       10
    10        Oshana      176674       10
    11      Oshikoto      181973       10
    12  Otjozondjupa      143903       10
    13        Khomas      342141       10
```

i need to divide 'Population' by 'New_val' and output 'Divided'(new column), all within one 3 parameter function e.g

```
def divide(x,y,z):
    x = Population
    y = New_val
    z = Divided
```

Required output

```
          REGION_NAM  Population  New_val  Divided
    0        Zambezi       90596       10       9059.6
    1         Erongo      150809       10      15080.9
    2         Hardap       79507       10       7950.7
    3          Karas       77421       10       7742.1
    4   Kavango West      223352       10      22335.2
    5   Kavango East      223352       10      22335.2
    6         Kunene       86856       10       8685.6
    7      Ohangwena      245446       10      24544.6
    8        Omaheke       71233       10       7123.3
    9        Omusati      243166       10      24316.6
    10        Oshana      176674       10      17667.4
    11      Oshikoto      181973       10      18197.3
    12  Otjozondjupa      143903       10      14390.3
    13        Khomas      342141       10      34214.1
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Isn't enough to do `data['Divided'] = data['Population'] / data['New_val']`? Since new_val is constant, you can even skip that column creation and do directly `data['Divided'] = data['Population'] / 10`.

Comment: @Itay lol yes it is homework, a little new to this. I agree using `data['Divided'] = data['Population'] / data['New_val']` would be the fastest option, but is it not possible to define a function that i could simply call using `print(Devide(data))` ?